# Opening Resources in Text File Format in Notepad

Tags: vb.net, file, resources, text-files, notepad

I'm having some trouble using resource files.

In my project I'm using a bunch of bitmap files and two txt files. Bitmaps are used as backgrounds for controls, but .txt files I want to open in Notepad or WordPad. 
Till now I was accesing them from a file path on my machine:

`ControlName.backgroundimage = New Bitmap(direcorypath & "/Map.bmp")`

`Process.Start(direcorypath & "/Instrukcje.txt")`

And it worked fine. Now I added these files to my resources (it's practical for me to have them in executable file)
And replaced those lines with:

`ControlName.backgroundimage = New Bitmap(MyProject.My.Resources.Map)`

`Process.Start(MyProject.My.Resources.Instrukcje)`

For bitmap it works fine, but for txt file an error occurs saying that a file cannot be found. 
Interestin thing is: when I type "MyProject.My.Resources.Instrukcje" in "Watch" it shows the content of the file. So it is there, only not as a file? I think I am missing something here
I searched everywhere whats the thing, but couldn't find anything helpful. I will be gratefil for some clues. 
(And sorry if somethings unclear, my programming skills are much worse than my not-so-good English) 
Thanks:)

Comment: Nothing wrong with your English, Agata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources are embedded in your .dll or .exe file and therefore cannot be accessed with the Process class. You could write the .txt resource to a temp-directory and use Process to start the temp file there.

Additional info: I've added a .txt file to a Resource.resx file to test your question, and plain text is stored as a string in the resource file. Therefore, if you access the Resources.(InsertYourTextFilesName) property, the text within the textfile is returned.

In case you might want to know: binary files (e.g. non-plain-text files) are stored as byte array in the resource.resx and interned within the compiled assembly as such.

Comment: Thanks, Webleeuw, a temp file seems like a great idea, i'll try to do that:)

Comment: All right! I just used the resource as if it was an ordinary string and wrote it into a temporary file. And everything workes fine, thank you again :)